# How to aproach this: Sort results under same date

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to achieve something like this:
[image]

I am using Laravel, and for example to display the results I would do a foreach on the array and display the title, the body etc.
Example

```
@foreach($resArray as $res)
    {{$res->Title}}
@endforeach
```

And that will display the title of each result in the array, I also have the date in `$res->startDate` but I am not sure how to list each result with same date under their specific date.
You probably didn't understood..

So for example if I have two notifications from `10/07/2017` and one from `11/07/2017` they will display as this:

```
10/07/2017
- notification 1
- notification 2

11/07/2017
- notification
```

I was thinking at an if statement but what statement
`if($res->startDate)` what so this won't work either, I was thinking to store them in arrays, for example array of date `11/07/2017` and display those arrays but would that even work...

Couldn't find too much from google as I am not too sure how to google this in a good maneer.

### EDIT 1

I tried doing this:

```
$notifResult = notifications::where('userID', '=', $userID)->select('*')->groupBy(['date'])->get();
        dd($notifResult);
```

but it didn't work, first of all, I had 3 results in database, it only got 2 of them and it didn't even group them by date, the two results that are listed before are from different days...

[image]

### EDIT 2

I added toArray to it and this is what I've got:
[image]

still, it only picks two results...

Comment: You've said that multiple approaches wouldn't work, but have you actually tried anything? Show an attempt that you've made and describe what problems you're having with it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting flat array into an array grouped by categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46490260/converting-flat-array-into-an-array-grouped-by-categories)

Comment: @PatrickQ But I have no idea how to even write one of those aproaches thats why I was looking for some suggestions.

Comment: @Marky The possible duplicate that I marked there is very close to the same concept, except change the word "categories" with "dates". The answer there should be able to give you a good idea of what you need to do.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton This really helps me, can you post it as an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: you want to display you data like this - 10/07/2017
- notification 1
- notification 2

11/07/2017
- notification

Comment: @Marky It's already posted as an answer, on the other question. It wouldn't be fair of me to take the credit for it. Just upvote it over there, and this question will likely be closed.

Comment: laravel has a group by on collection and you can use them

Comment: group by on db not an answer , because group your data on mysql , you must use group_concat if you want all rows , but on laravel collection work's as you want

Answer (score 0):

One naive but simple solution is to sort the results by start date and then in the foreach check if the previous date (store it in temp var) is different from the current one, and if true display the new date.

```
$prevDate = '';

@foreach($resArray as $res)
    @if($prevDate != '' && $prevDate != $res->startDate) {
        //do sth to break the html and display the new date
    @endif

    {{$res->Title}}
    {{$prevDate = $res->startDate;}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: This is a decent solution. Prevents the overhead of creating a new object or array, and is pretty flexible.

Comment: I don't think `blade` templating allows assignment like that (unless it's changed recently). `{{ $key = $value; }}` might have to be changed to `<?php $key = $value; ?>` for this to work without throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your problem you must use group by

```
$collection = collect([
    ['date' => '10/07/2017', 'title' => 'notification 1'],
    ['date' => '10/07/2017', 'title' => 'notification 2'],
    ['date' => '11/07/2017', 'title' => 'notification'],
]);

$grouped = $collection->groupBy('date');

$grouped->toArray();
dd($grouped);
```

[image]

Comment: I edited my first post with what I've tried, can you check that please?