# Creating a meet the team page, want to order by descending level and each level onto new row

Tags: php, html, css, sql

I'm developing a Meet the Team page for my website. Here's how it looks so far (http://prntscr.com/gynyrj).

As you can see, it's in descending order. But, what I'm trying to achieve is so that each new level would go onto the next row. e.g. administrators level 7 at the top, administrators level 6 on the next row, administrators level 5 on the next and so on..

Something like this (http://prntscr.com/gyo1pc)

```
$query = $con->prepare("SELECT * from playerdata WHERE pAdmin >= 1 ORDER BY 
`pAdmin` DESC");
$query->execute();

while($data = $query->fetch())
{
    ...panel code
}
```

Regards,

Daniel

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. It looks like this is a layout issue, not a query issue.

Comment: @tmwoods I didn't say it was a query issue. Anyway, I think a loop is required to loop through each level and place them onto a new row?

Comment: @DannyBarbosa You think a loop is required to loop through data? I'd say your pretty spot on, and what you have looks correct to me so far.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton What I have so far is only ordering the staff-panels in descending order. I want only one row to contain a certain level. For example, the top row would contain administrators level 7, the second row of panels would contain administrators level 6 and so on...

Comment: What is `pAdmin`, is that what holds the administrator level?

Comment: Yes, pAdmin is the administrator level.

Comment: @DannyBarbosa What I would recommend is checking out the answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46490260/converting-flat-array-into-an-array-grouped-by-categories - basically what you want to do is group all of your team members by their administrator level, then you will have a multi-dimensional array that will have the administrator level has the key, and several sub-arrays under each of those that contains the information about your team members. Then you just loop through the array for the administrator level, and have a sub loop to list the team members.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Still not quite sure how to do it. I've read through the topic. Sorry hah, I'm not the best when it comes to php. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possible solution. Create a 2D array that stores the `$data` arrays in your loop, using `pAdmin` as the first dimension's key:

```
$query = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM `playerdata` WHERE `pAdmin` >= 1 ORDER BY `pAdmin` DESC");
$query->execute();

$playersByAdminLevel = array();

while($data = $query->fetch()) {
    $adminLevel = $data['pAdmin'];
    $playersByAdminLevel[$adminLevel][] = $data;
}
```

You can now do a nested loop over the `$playersByAdminLevel` array:

```
foreach($playersByAdminLevel as $players) {
    foreach($players as $player) {
        // $player['name'] etc.
    }
    echo '<br>\n'; // ... or whatever html you need to start the next row
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks for the help! I've got one more thing though, if you don't mind me asking. How can I centre the panels in the middle of the page? (like this - http://prntscr.com/gyph6u)

Comment: You should create a new question for that; post the relevant HTML and styles.